# Select CollectionView cell by swipe left (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

How to select a collectionView cell by swiping left like show in example?

I tried to find information on how to do this, but could not find.

**Example**

[image: gif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a drag gesture to the collection view.
2. When the gesture begins ask the collection view for the index path of the cell it began in, then make a snapshot view and place a white view over the collection view cell.
3. As the drag continues in the correct direction, animated the snapshot to follow it until it reaches the threshold.
4. remove the snapshot and the white view and select the cell and reload it.